# Closedness v.s. convergent sequence

Tags: general-topology

When are the following statements equivalent?

1. A subset $A \subset X$ is closed for the given topology on $X$.
2. Every sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $A$ that converge to $a \in X$, we must have $a\in A$.

Comment: 1 always implies 2, in any space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are exactly equivalent in so-called [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space). These include all spaces that are first countable (but also more general non first-countable spaces, e.g. all quotient images of metrisable spaces, like $\Bbb R{/}\Bbb Z$).

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ first countable?

Comment: @egreg It's the identification of $\Bbb Z$ to a point, not the group quotient which is $\Bbb S^1$..